# how to search using a date in one column across 2 date columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any suggestions?

i have a table tblInstallBase where i have to pass the parameter WarrantyEnd date to search if it falls in between dates

MFGWarrantyStartDt1
and MFGWarrantyStartDt2

it is a normal warranty 
    or

if it falls in between

MFGWarrantyStartDt2 and MFGWarrantyExpDt2 it is ExtendedWarranty

Comment: Hi,query to search with join condition on different column? when i execute it has to take WarrantyDate Parameter. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a union for the best possible index usage:

```
select 'Normal' as TypeOf,* from tblInstallBase 
where @givenDate>=MFGWarrantyStartDt1 and @givenDate<=MFGWarrantyStartDt2
union all
select 'extended',* from tblInstallBase 
where @givenDate>=MFGWarrantyStartDt2 and @givenDate<=MFGWarrantyExpDt2
```

Comment: just make sure you have an index on MFGWarrantyStartDt1+MFGWarrantyStartDt2 and one on MFGWarrantyStartDt2+MFGWarrantyExpDt2 and this query should run using it and not a complete slow table scan.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN @WarrantyEnd BETWEEN MFGWarrantyStartDt2 AND MFGWarrantyExpDt2 THEN 'ExtendedWarranty'
    ELSE 'Normal Warranty' END
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
case when @WarrantyEnd between MFGWarrantyStartDt1  and MFGWarrantyStartDt2 then 'Normal Warranty'
when @WarrantyEnd between MFGWarrantyStartDt2 and MFGWarrantyExpDt2  then 'Extended Warranty'
else 'Expired' end
from @warantee
```

Note, if the @WarrantyEnd falls on MFGWarrantyStartDt2 then it is "Normal Warranty" as the first condition will be satisfied